# Draw checkmark in rowdata using jsPDF Autotable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Ive'd been searching every possible solution anywhere but landed on nothing.

How do we put a checkmark (✓) `\u2713` in a row?

```
generateRowData(rows: any): any {
   return rows.map(r => [r.name.toUpperCase(), r.is_check? '\u2713' : '']);
}
```

But all i got is is a single quote `'` instead of a ✓

Comment: Try outputting it with the `doc.text` function. If that doesn't work, I would be surprised if it was anyway of doing it other than drawing the checkmark yourself with `doc.line` etc. If you can get it to work with `doc.text`, but not with autoTable it would be great if you could report it as a bug in the github repository.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson ill try your suggestion, but anyway i was able to draw a shape in autotable hook drawCell function, but the drawn shape is overlayed by the cell.

Comment: Yeh, there is an issue with this in v2. Fixed in v3, if you are adventures you can try the alpha release of that. It is highly experimental though.

Comment: lets give it a try then